# How to dynamically change the text of the Global: result summary based on exposed filter on Views?

Tags: 7, views

There is a content type and it has a field called `field_type`. It's a select list and there is 5 options to select such as AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD, EEE.

I'm using the Views module to list the nodes of this content type. I added the field_type as exposed filter for this views.

In the header of the views, I added the `Global: Result summary` to show result summary.

```
 "@total results found."
```

[image]

What I want to do is dynamically change the text based on the exposed filter. For example if the AAA is selected on the `field_type` exposed filter then the results summary should display:

```
 "@total AAA found."
```

**How can I do that?**

Comment: Did you have a chance to try out the module I posted? I believe it answers your question and solves your problem. You can install it as a you would with any other contrib module. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by implementing the [hook_views_pre_render](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7) and altering the view's header content. Here is a sample code:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_pre_render().
 */
function my_module_views_pre_render(&$view) {
  if ($view->name == 'my_view' && $view->current_display == 'my_display') {
    $indicator = $view->exposed_input['my_filter'] == 1 ? t('AAA ') : t('BBB ');
    $view->header['result']->options['content'] = '<div class="my-class-results">@total <strong><em>' . $indicator . '</strong></em> found</div>';
  }
}
```

This works with any substitution: `@start, @end, @total, @name` etc

Answer (score 1):

I took the liberty of writing a little module for accomplishing what you asked for, I found it an interesting problem.
You can access it here:

https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/stefanos.petrakis/2666048

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer and for the "sandbox" module. I have to learn how to use this kind of modules :)

Comment: Do give it a try and please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Unfortunately it gives some error. I will try to solve the errors myself, if I couldn't I will write them here. Thanks.

Comment: Hello @herci. Did you get this to work? What is the problem you are facing with installing this module? Cheers